# with bgl deprecated in b3.5+ how to compensate for loss of GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL and bgl.glPolygonOffset

Tags: scripting, bgl, glsl

I'm wondering how others have solved this problem now `bgl` is being deprecated. We have a few places in the Sverchok drawing code where we avoid zfighting between edges and faces by including GL code like

```py
   bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL)
   bgl.glPolygonOffset(1.0, 1.0)
```

but now that's being removed, the drawing will look like this

[image]

any insights are welcome!

Comment: Hello ! You may have some luck asking developers directly over on https://blender.chat/channel/python ?

Comment: thanks @Gorgious , I did ask this question there too. no response yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using a Geometry Shader.

I used the following references:

- https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2120983&seqNum=2
- https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/pull/4983#issuecomment-1704295764
- and a generic function to calculate the normal of a polygon.

I am under no illusion that this is the optimal approach, and it definitely needs tweaking regarding edge cornercases.

#### Vertex Shader

```c
uniform mat4 viewProjectionMatrix;
in vec3 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = viewProjectionMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0f);
}
```

#### Geometry Shader

```c
uniform mat4 viewProjectionMatrix;
out VS_OUT
{
    vec3 FaceNormal;
} vs_out;

layout(triangles) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;

void main()
{
    vec3 ab = gl_in[1].gl_Position.xyz - gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz;
    vec3 ac = gl_in[2].gl_Position.xyz - gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz;
    vec3 normal3 = normalize(cross(ab, ac));
    vec4 normal4 = vec4(normal3, 1.0);
    vs_out.FaceNormal = normal3;
    vec4 rescale = vec4(0.00003, 0.00003, 0.00003, 0.0);
    vec4 offset = vec4(normal4 * rescale);

    for (int i = 0; i < gl_in.length(); i++)
    {
        gl_Position = gl_in[i].gl_Position + offset;
        EmitVertex();
    }

    EndPrimitive();        
}
```

#### Fragment Shader

```c
in VS_OUT
{
    vec3 FaceNormal;
} fs_in;

out vec4 gl_FragColor;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(fs_in.FaceNormal.xyz, 0.7);
}
```

and in this case I wanted to color the polygons based on their computed normal.

[image]

As you notice, the edges which are on contours still suffer a bit of z-fighting, but I can live with that for now.